# Ошибка в конфигурации Gulp

Tags: gulp

листинг -- всё в одном файле:

```
 var gulp = require('gulp');
 var compass = require( 'gulp-compass' );
 var notify = require( 'gulp-notify' );
 var livereload = require( 'connect-livereload' );
 var connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
  root: 'app',
 livereload: true
 });
 });

 gulp.task( 'compass', function(){
 gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
  .pipe(compass({
      config_file: 'config.rb',
      css: 'css',
      sass: 'sass'
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
  .pipe(connect.reload());
  //.pipe(notify('Done!'));
}); 

 gulp.task('html', function(){
  gulp.src('index.html')
 .pipe(connect.reload());
  });

 gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('sass/*.scss', ['compass']);
  gulp.watch('index.html', ['html']);

 });

 gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'compass', 'html', 'watch']);
```

пробовал и

```
var livereload = require( 'connect-livereload' );
```

и

```
var livereload = require( 'gulp-livereload' );
```

но выдаёт всё тоже

> Cannot GET /

Дерево проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Директорию, которую просматривает сервер 
`root: 'app'`.

А твои таски что-то делают, а выплёвывают файлы не в эту директорию.

Поменяй в тасках пути dest 
Например: `.pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))`

Или поменяй директорию просмотра сервером на `'/'`

Comment: Спасибо, но теперь другая проблема https://yadi.sk/i/Ckd0A0ht3FeSFc

Comment: сейчас в гулп файле поменял пути https://yadi.sk/i/bpUiRcS33FeSPh,
но при запуске вылетает такая ошибка https://yadi.sk/i/cGjKJHtR3FeSXc

Comment: подскажи, где я опять накосячил?

Comment: понял я в чём дело 
            css: 'dev/css',
            sass: 'dev/sass'
здесь надо было тоже путь поменять